# Count The Employees in Each category ( Two Tables )

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables ( employee , Job )

```
Employee Table
Emp_no   Nationality_id  Job_Code  
1          966            99
2          996            89
3          258            10
4          123            10
5          123            20
6          987            10
```

Job Table

```
Job_Code    Job_Category
99          Finance
89          Finance
10          HR
20          IT
```

i need the result to:
1-  count all employees based on the job_category for nationality_id = 966 as Count1

2-   count all employees based on the job_category for nationality_id <> 966 as Count2

the wanted result like this:

```
Job_Category    Count 1 Count 2
Finance           2       0
HR                0       3
IT                0       1
```

Thanks

Great

i need to add also sum 1  and sum 2  to the result

table salary

```
Emp_id     Salary
1          1000
2          3000
3          1500
```

1- sum all employees Salary based on the job_category for nationality_id = 966 as sum_1

2- sum all employees salary based on the job_category for nationality_id <> 966 as sum_2

The Final result is

```
Job_Category    Count 1 Count 2  Sum1   Sum 2
Finance           2       0      4000    0
HR                0       3      0       1500
IT                0       1      0       0
```

Comment: Would you show us your actual query ?

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
WITH groups as (

    Select 

    CASE WHEN nationality_id = 966 then Count1
    Else Count2 END as count_group,
    Emp_no

    from employees

)

Select 

j.Job_Category as Job_Category,
CASE WHEN (g.count_group = Count1) then COUNT(distinct e.Emp_no)
ELSE 0 END as Count1,
CASE WHEN (g.count_group = Count2) then COUNT(distinct e.Emp_no)
ELSE 0 END as Count2

FROM employees as e

LEFT JOIN groups g on e.Emp_no = g.Emp_no 
LEFT JOIN Jobs j on e.Job_Code = j.Job_Code
```

Answer (score 0):

This is conditional aggregation.  The only real trick is an outer join for `salary`.

```
select j.job_category,
       sum(case when e.nationality = 966 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_966,
       sum(case when e.nationality = 966 then 0 else 1 end) as cnt_other,
       sum(case when e.nationality = 966 then s.salary else 0 end) as salary_966,
       sum(case when e.nationality = 966 then 0 else s.salary end) as salary_other,
from employees e join
     jobs j
     on e.job_code = j.job_code left join
     salary s
     on s.emp_no = e.emp_no
group by j.job_category;
```